# Android: Merge test project with main project

Tags: android, eclipse, git, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a project, say "MyProject", located in ~/workspaces/MyProject, and the corresponding test project "MyProjectTest" located in ~/workspaces/MyProjectTest. They have their own git repo. I'm running the Robolectric test framework for my test project.

Now, I'd like to merge them into one project, or at least move the MyProjectTest source code into the MyProject git repo.

Any advice on how to best accomplish this?

Best regards,
kenneho

Comment: I would use submodules. That would be still two separate repositories, but you can check the both out in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice. I ended up doing this:
Move the MyProjectTest source files into folder "MyProject/tests", and - from the MyProjectTest project - created a link (in Eclipse) to that destination. I then added the new source files to the MyProject git repo. Seems to be working fine.